# Min and Max in python?

Tags: python

*Can someone please, explain to me how the min and max work? I am really struggling to understand what is happening.*

```
ask_user = int(input("How many integers would you like to enter?\n"))
n = ask_user
print("please enter",str(ask_user) + " integers" )
min = 999
max = 0
for i in range(0, n):
    k = int(input())
    if k < min:
       min = k
    if k > max:
        max = k
print("min:", min)
print("max:", max
```

)

Comment: Its finding the smallest and largest numbers in the input. But, please don't use those names -- they are existing functions in Python, rename to something else, e.g. `smallest` & `largest` or `minimum` & `maximum`

Comment: `min = 999` is also not robust..

Comment: You could simply this code by reading the values into a list and then use the actual `min()`/`max()` functions to get the minimum & maximum.

Comment: What is your specific question? Also, you aren’t using python’s min and max functions. You are creating variables called min and max. But, what specifically are you confused about?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What are you confused about exactly? This code does exactly what it says and I don't see anything too confusing about it (except `n = ask_user`, which is kind of pointless). Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are asking the user to input `ask_user` amount of integer numbers and then finding the `max` number and `min` number. Although it is not recommended to code as `max=0` and `min=999`, what is happening here is whenever a number **greater** than the current `max` value is put in, it replaces the previous `max` value with `k`. This is the same for `min`, whenever a number **smaller** than current `min` value is put in, it replaces the current `min` value with `k`.

You should actually first get a list of numbers and then use python functions `min()/max()` to do this. It is a much better way.

Comment: thank you for your help; my brain just can not comprehend it it for some reasons. I am just starting in programming.

Comment: why is the vice versa? can you write in an example?

Comment: Say you entered `ask_user` as 3 so now your for loop will run and input 3 integers.
Lets enter these 3 numbers like 7, 777, 77.
Now that the `min` is initialized as 999, and `max` is initialized with 0, when we input number 7, it compares `7 < min` which is true and sets 7 as the new min number. Then it compares `7 > max` which is true as well so it sets 7 as new max.
Now when we input 777, it compares `777 < 7` which is not true, and `777 > 7` which is true and thus sets 777 as new `max` number.
and for 77, `77<7` is not true and `77 > 777` is also not true and thus no changes occur.

Comment: thank you so much for your clear explanation, I can understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a new integer (k) is inputted by the user k is compared with the current largest and smallest values. If k is smaller than the smallest value, the the smallest value becomes the value of k. If k is  larger than the largest value, the largest value becomes the value of k.

Comment: Glad to help! Welcome to StackOverflow and Python!